How can I count repeats in a a column but reset count on non-repeats, in an array formula
I have data like this where there's just two words I need to check at any time.
I cant figure out how to count the duplicates but break the counting if there is another value inbetween.



Column A
Desired Result




Apple
1


Apple
2


Apple
3


Pears
1


Pears
2



(No match value because empty cell - resets count)


Pears
1


Pears
2


Apple
1


Pears
2



=ArrayFormula(iferror(SORT(ROW(D3:D),SORT(ROW(D3:D),D3:D,1),1)-MATCH(D3:D,SORT(D3:D),0)-ROW()+1))
This counts as I expect, but doesnt break the chain and doesnt let me specify the words though that may not be a problem..

Running sums can usually be done by SCAN:
=SCAN(1,A3:A12,LAMBDA(a,c,IF(c=OFFSET(c,-1,0),a+1,1)))

Here, we just add 1 to the accumulator, IF current value  is equal to previous row's value(OFFSET by -1 row)

This is exactly what I needed, thanks! Scan and lambda are new to me, I will need to read into those. I felt like offset was key as well but couldnt make it work properly with an array formula, but it seems like scan/lambda makes this an array by itself. Thank you so much!

I'm not sure what the best way to do draw this on SO, but basically, you want to compare adjacent cells and increment if same and reset to 1 if not, right?

A1: "Apple"          B1: 1
A2: "Apple"          B2: =if(A2=A1, B1+1, 1)
A3: "Apple"          B3: =if(A3=A2, B2+1, 1)
(and so on)


I've accepted the above more complex answer but I struggled with this for so long and your simpler formula is absolutely working as well if I make it into an array and just add a helper column for numbers. Thank you!
=ArrayFormula(IF(C3:C=1,C3:C,If(D3:D=D2:D,O2:O+1,1)))
